# Write $x = y$ in intercept form of line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:** Write the intercept form for the line $y=x$.

---

After learning about intercept form of line i.e. $\dfrac{x}{a} + \dfrac{y}{b} = 1$ where $a$ is $x$ intercept and $b$ is $y$ intercept, my confusion is that how to convert the equation $y=x$ in this intercept form?

Since there is no intercept (or we can say the distances $a$ and $b$ are $0$), so the intercept form should be $\dfrac x0 + \dfrac y0 = 1$ which I don't think make any sense since division by $0$ is not defined.

So can't we write this equation in intercept form? This seems to be an exceptional case.

Comment: Basically, the intercept form of the equation of the line doesn't exist when the line is $x=a$, $y=b$, or $y=kx$

Comment: I think this format is commonly called the symmetric form of a line, and is indeed inapplicable when either intercept is $0.$ Notice that even $y=mx+c$ isn't general enough, since it is inapplicable when the line is vertical. And [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/25317/how-do-i-teach-the-difference-between-linear-equations-and-equation-of-a-line/25319#comment64631_25317), I pointed out that even $ax+by+cz+d=0$ (which does give vertical and $0$-intercept lines) doesn't give a straight line, if it lives in 3D space.